# Open GL Translucid Sprites

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, rendering, sprite

So, my goal is to draw sprites with translucid pixels.

First, I render the sprites with a shader that only renders the opaque pixels. Then, I disable depth buffer writing and render the same sprites with a shader that only renders the translucid (or transparent sprites), as explained here:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51202/how-do-you-display-non-cutout-transparent-2d-textures-with-a-depth-buffer-open

This is the animation sprite sheet I am using as test:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMs2W.png

This is my renderer update function:

```
updateRenderData();

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glUseProgram(_programID);
render();

glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glUseProgram(_translucencyPogramID);
render();


_window->SwapBuffers();
```

And this is my render function (just in case you want to know how I render the sprites):

```
GLint baseInstance = 0;
GLsizei spriteCount;

for (int i = 0; i < _spriteManager->GetSpriteBatchVector()->size(); i++)
{
    _SpriteBatch* spriteBatch = _spriteManager->GetSpriteBatchVector()->at(i);
    setTexture(spriteBatch->GetTexture());
    spriteCount = (GLsizei)spriteBatch->GetSpriteVector()->size();
    glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance(_quad.renderMode, _quad.indexCount, _quad.indexDataType, 0, spriteCount, baseInstance);
    baseInstance += spriteCount;
}
```

But when I execute this code, it only renders the translucid pixels:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4AY6.png

In fact, nothing renders (black screen) if I remove the second *render()* call (only the call, I still change the shader and set the depth mask to false), like this:

```
updateRenderData();

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glUseProgram(_programID);
render();

glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glUseProgram(_translucencyPogramID);


_window->SwapBuffers();
```

But if I don't change the shader nor set glDepthMask to false after the first render, it renders the opaque pixels of my sprites correctly.

Edit:
This is the fragment shader I am using for the second pass:

```
out layout(location = 0) vec4 outColor;

in vec2 texCoord;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
    vec4 texel = texture(tex, texCoord);
    if(texel.a == 1)
    {
        discard;
    }
    outColor = texel;
}
```

The first pass is just the same, but discarding if alpha < 1.
The vertex shader is standard.

So, my question here is: what is causing this?

Edit 2:

To clarify, this renders correctly (without translucent pixels):

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glUseProgram(_programID);
render();
```

And this doesn't render at all:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glUseProgram(_programID);
render();

glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);//Just added this line
```

And this also doesn't render at all:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glUseProgram(_programID);
render();

glUseProgram(_translucencyPogramID);//Just added this line
```

Comment: What does your shader look like?

Comment: None of the code above, would result in what you're showing as is. It would help to know why you have 2 shaders?

Comment: "First, I render the sprites with a shader that only renders the opaque pixels. Then, I disable depth buffer writing and render the same sprites with a shader that only renders the translucid (or transparent sprites)". Maybe its not the best way of doing it but I wanted to try it.

Comment: And also yea, this is only a fraction of a more complex rendering system, but it is too complex to put it in here. The question is why using glDepthMask(GL_FALSE) and glUseProgram(_translucencyPogramID) AFTER the rendering affects the rendering.

Comment: So you want the fully opaque bird drawn and then draw the translucent red background on top after?

Comment: Not on top, depth testing (but not writing to depth buffer) is still enabled. But yea, the idea is to draw first the opaque pixels and then the translucid ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `_programID` is for drawing the opaque part of the bird and `_translucencyPogramID` is for drawing the translucent part.

Nothing in the code you've supplied shows what the cause could be. However it could be the result of:

1. You aren't actually calling `render()` while using `_programID`.
2. After the `_programID` you `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`
3. You're using `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` as `glBlendFunc()`'s `sfactor`

So given that your `_programID`'s fragment shader consists of:

```
if (texel.a < 1.0)
    discard;
```

and your `_translucencyPogramID`'s fragment shader consists of:

```
if (texel.a == 1.0)
    discard;
```

Then granted your draw loop is like this (pseudo-code):

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)
glUseProgram(_programID)
for each sprite
    glDrawArrays(....)

glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)
glUseProgram(_translucencyPogramID)
for each sprite
    glDrawArrays(....)

glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)
```

Then while using `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`, then that should give the desired result.

**Edit**

Then reason it breaks when you when you add `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)`, is because you don't enabled it again after. You can check this by doing:

```
GLboolean enabled;
glGetBooleanv(GL_DEPTH_WRITEMASK, &enabled);
assert(enabled == GL_TRUE);
```

Before you `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`.

This reason it breaks is because if writing to the depth buffer is disabled, then `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` won't do anything, and thus leave the depth buffer as is.

As you can see below, on the second picture it sort of smears the silhouette of all the bird's frames. Which is because the depth buffer is never cleared, and this bird is the frontmost bird. If writing to the depth buffer is enabled upon calling `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` then it correctly yields the first picture.

[image: correct]
[image: wrong]

*Left: Depth writing is enabled on glClear. Right: Depth writing is disabled on glClear.*

Note that this relation is true for `glClear(...)` and any `gl*Mask(GL_FALSE)`.

Comment: Thaks for taking your time with the answer. Your assumptions about _programID and _translucidProgramID are correct. But the problem persists. I call render() while using _programID, I do not call glClear after it and I am using glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA), so those are not the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thank you, that solved part of the problem. But the problem still persists since if I change the shader after the first render (only adding the line glUseProgram(_translucencyProgramID);) it still doesn't render anything. I edited the question again (sorry for the amount of edits).

Comment: Adding that line shouldn't make it not render anymore. So currently I can't add anything besides what I already wrote in my answer. Feel free to edit the question more, so we can get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Ok I've narrowed down the problem of the shader thing and it looks its a bug from another part of the code (the code that compiles the shaders), so I will mark this as the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Alright and you're welcome! If you haven't already consider enabling [debug output](https://learnopengl.com/#!In-Practice/Debugging) (it's a bit far down the page). It's a really nice utility for noticing any error happening.